# Debug COM object in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I have a third party add in that integrates with Outlook 2007. This third party add in allows you to write your own COM based add in's to work with the product. I have a COM object written in Visual Studio 2013. (At least I think it is a COM object created in Visual Studio) The class has the following attribute. (Actual guid withheld)

```
[Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClassName : IVendorInterface {
```

Is there anyway I can attach to a process in order to debug this MyClassName.cs? I have tried attaching to Outlook.exe directly, but that does not work. Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible? (and if so, how can I accomplish such a thing?)

Thanks

Comment: Use the 'Debugger.Break()' statement. Put it just before the source code where you want to start debugging.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do to go along with that? Tried it while being attached to Outlook.exe, but no luck. It just skipped right past it.

Comment: You start Outlook in the normal way (no debugging). When 'Debugger.Break()' is encountered, it will show in VS as if a breakpoint was hit.